# Entity Repository

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony-2

Eu tenho as tabelas:

```
Operário(id,identidade(string));
Intervenção (data(date), hora(time), duracao(integer));
Avaria (data(date), descricao(string), impedimento(boolean));
Prevista (contagem(integer), duracao(integer), fazer(string), tempo(integer), ficha(string));
```

E tenho o repository feito.

```
class IntervencaoRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function getRecentIntervencao($number = 30) {
        $dql = "SELECT b, e, r FROM Bug b JOIN b.engineer e JOIN b.reporter r ORDER BY b.created DESC";
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        $query->setMaxResults($number);
        return $query->getResult();
    }

    public function getRecentIntervencaoArray($number = 30) {
        $dql = "SELECT b, e, r, p FROM Bug b JOIN b.engineer e ".
               "JOIN b.reporter r JOIN b.products p ORDER BY b.created DESC";
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        $query->setMaxResults($number);
        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }

    public function getUsersIntervencao($userId, $number = 15) {
        $dql = "SELECT b, e, r FROM Bug b JOIN b.engineer e JOIN b.reporter r ".
               "WHERE b.status = 'OPEN' AND e.id = ?1 OR r.id = ?1 ORDER BY b.created DESC";
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql) ->setParameter(1, $userId) ->setMaxResults($number) ->getResult();
    }

    public function getOpenIntervencaoByProduct() {
        $dql = "SELECT p.id, p.name, count(b.id) AS openBugs FROM Bug b ".
               "JOIN b.products p WHERE b.status = 'OPEN' GROUP BY p.id";
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)->getScalarResult();
    }
}
```

E eu queria na `IntervencaoController` chamar os parâmetros/variáveis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua entidade `Intervencao` você deve declarar o repositório que acabou de criar para ele:

```
<?php

namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity;

use use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IntervencaoRepository")
 */
class Intervencao
{
    // resto da classe
}
```

Depois é só usar o `EntityManager` do Doctrine para acessar seu repositório e seus respectivos métodos.

```
<?php

namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class IntervencaoController extends Controller
{
    public function qualquerMetodoAction()
    {
        $intervencao = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Intervencao')->getRecentIntervencao();
        // $intervencao = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Intervencao')->getRecentIntervencaoArray();
        // $intervencao = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Intervencao')->getUsersIntervencao($this->getUser()->getId());
        // $intervencao = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Intervencao')-> getOpenIntervencaoByProduct();

        return $intervencao;
    }
}
```

PS: depois coloque os *namespaces* das suas classes para que eu possa complementar a resposta.

Comment: Intervencao.php : namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity; IntervencaoController : namespace RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Controller;

Comment: Não sei se precisa de mais alguma, mas se precisar diga-me.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja se funciona.

Comment: porque é que o texto esta editado?

Comment: Porque eu coloquei os namespaces que você comentou e também as entidades dos repositórios no Controller.